# MySql icon missing from System Preferences panel

Tags: mysql, macos, system-preferences

I'm trying to restart mysql (a whole different question), MySql is definitely installed (version 14.14), and from what i gather i SHOULD be seeing an icon for it toward the bottom of my System Preferences panel, but it's not there. Did something get botched during the install? Thanks for the help, beginner here! hah

Answer (score 2):

An old question but for anyone else confused with this -- restart your system if you can't find "mysql" icon in the System Preference. I was able to see the option after restarting.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use `mysql.server start` to start my MySQL server. Never heard of a GUI or icon in the system preferences?

Answer (score 0):

/Library/PreferencePanes/MySQL.prefPane

click on MYSQL.prefpane

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I did a spot light search for "Preference Pane" then clicked the icon and it opened "MySql". I do not know how or why the MySql icon is not showing in the applications. I crated an ilias for "Preference Pane" on the desktop and started using that when I want to open MySql.